# Any statistical test to find difference between two paired data with one sample?

Tags: statistics, correlation, spss

I have two sets of data related to ONLY **one sample**. One set is collected under condition/environment A and the other one under B. I need to show that the data collected using A and B have statistically significant correlation and are not by chance. However, the test like paired sample t-test does not seem to work as I have only 1 sample.

The sample in each A and B condition/environment is being generated 30 times. I know this is not proper use of statistics, but due to some industrial limits, we are unable to run the test for more than one sample now. The only solution came to my mind is to find the difference between the data generated from A and B. But, is there any alternative or statistically accepted method to do so? Does the measured difference between data A and B worthy piece of information? Can we rely on that?

I use SPSS for my work.

Thanks

Comment: I think this question would be better at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), as it is seeking statistical advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do have two samples: two dependent samples. You have one sample, but you are measuring twice. For a paired samples t-test, you must make sure that your data are structured as 'wide'. This means that each subject is placed in only one row, and each subject has two scores (two variables). In your case, the first variable is the score given condition A and the second variable is the score given condition B. The data should look something like:

```
Subject   A   B
1        30  40
2        22  60
3        26  80
...
30       10  55
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is not the case. It is the normal and correct way of doing so. But what I wanted was not as clear and correct as you explained. Anyhow thanks.